# Odd "double callback" when using hide/show jquery animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, show-hide

Ive got a div thats hidden with .hide and on click opens using `.show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);` which all works fine, inside of that ive got button that on click triggers the div to be hidden, this is done using

```
$('.hide-content').click(function () {
     $(".slide-out").hide("slide", {
         direction: "left"
     }, 1000);
});
```

it works, but once its hidden it opens again and then closes really quickly.. its really odd as i cant see that theres any js causing it.

ive made a fiddle of the problem here - http://jsfiddle.net/vUZuY/ - to replicate it : click OPEN then scroll to the bottom of the opened div and hit hide and you'll see how it bounces back open after it closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I noticed two problems with this:

1. You were re-binding the hide event *every time you opened the div*. It looks like you're loading from another source, though, so this might be fine in your actual implementation.
2. **Real Issue**: In your markup, you have the "Close" link within and a paragraph within them. Both have the class "hide-content" -- so you've set it up to fire this event twice. (Once when the  is clicked and once when the

   is clicked);

I made a quick edit to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vUZuY/2/ by giving the  a unique id and binding to that.